# $\Sigma^{+}$ baryon decay- why no decays to neutron and electron-neutrino pair?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, baryons

I am working on a homework problem involving a decay of the form

$\Sigma^+\rightarrow n+e^++\nu_e$,

with the goal of providing justification for why this decay is not experimentally observed. To solve the problem, I tried creating a Feynman diagram based on weak interactions, and was expecting to find that I would not be able to get what I wanted as final products. However, that was not the case$-$I ended up with the Feynman diagram shown here:
[Feynman diagram http://realbooktunes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/sigmabaryondecay.png](http://realbooktunes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/sigmabaryondecay.png)

The diagram consists of two seemingly common weak interactions, with the end result of a neutron and the positron-neutrino pair I wanted. Is there something fundamentally wrong with the diagram, or is there a more subtle obstacle that prevents a decay of this form from occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Good question --- not least since $\Sigma^- \to \rm n e^-\bar\nu$ makes up about 0.1% of all $\Sigma^-$ decays.

The [Particle Data Group summary](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2016/tables/rpp2016-tab-baryons-Sigma.pdf) describes your decay $\Sigma^+\to\rm n e^+\nu$ as a decay mode that has $\Delta S \neq \Delta Q$ and groups it with some other unobserved decays which must have strangeness-changing neutral currents.  That's one hint.

Since you say this is homework, I'll leave you with another hint: how many weak vertices are there in your diagram? And how does that compare with diagrams for the dominant decay modes $\Sigma^+\to\rm p\pi^0$ and $\Sigma^+\to\rm n\pi^+$?